# Problemas com JARs

Tags: java, maven, jar

Estou com uma aplicação Spring que utiliza Maven. Todas as dependências estão no arquivo `pom.xml` ou os JARs encontram-se no meu repositório `.m2` local. Toda vez que tento executar a aplicação aparecem as mensagens a seguir:

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in 
C:\Users\local\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3\jaxb-impl-
2.2.3.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: 
C:\Users\local\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3\jaxb-
api.jar,C:\Users\local\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-
impl\2.2.3\jaxb1-impl.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in 
C:\Users\local\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar referenced 
one or more files that do not exist: 
C:\Users\local\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.2\xml-apis.jar
```

Conforme vou adicionando os JARs manualmente esses erros vão diminuindo porém ainda não encontrei todos os JARs para download. Alguma configuração adicional ao projeto poderia solucionar isso?

Comment: Você está usando algum plugin do maven para empacotamento? Coloca teu pom.xml aqui.

Comment: Estou tentando redigir uma resposta, mas começou a ficar complicado a parte de resolver o xalan. Poderia postar o seu `pom.xml`? Ou então, pelo menos dizer qual dependência sua usa o xalan?

Comment: Remove a pasta .m2, como voce utiliza o mavem, baixa todas as dependencias novamente, marcando a opção forçar atualização. Após baixar todas as dependencias, valide o programa, e tente executar outra vez. Geralmente funciona pra min...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do conteúdo do `MANIFEST.MF` do [`jaxb-impl-2.2.3.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3) há isso:

```
Class-Path: jaxb-api.jar activation.jar jsr173_1.0_api.jar jaxb1-impl.
 jar
```

Se você olhar o do [`jaxb-impl-2.2.11`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11) ou o do [`jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0):

```
Class-Path: jaxb-core.jar
```

Assim, sugiro realizar um upgrade e trocar a versão do `jaxb-impl`. Talvez isso seja o suficiente para resolver também o problema do xalan.

Se o problema do `xalan-2.7.2.jar` persistir, isso é um pouco mais difícil. No `MANIFEST.MF` dele há isso:

```
Class-Path: xercesImpl.jar xml-apis.jar serializer.jar
```

Não existe versão mais recente dele.

A solução então é simplesmente excluir o JAR problemático:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>xalan</groupId>
  <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

E se você precisar do `xml-apis` mesmo assim, nunca use uma versão 2.0.x, pois as versões 2.0.x são mais antigas e [a mais nova é a 1.4.01](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis) (olhe as datas dos JARs), por mais bizarro e idiota que isso seja. [Esse JAR é um grande causador de problemas de dependências](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11677572/540552), que embora foram supostamente corrigidos em 2013, ainda causam um monte de problemas por possibilitar que versões erradas desses arquivos JAR apareçam no seu classpath. Use a versão 1.4.01:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

Também recomendo você banir explicitamente dependências ruins que possam te causar problemas, tal como fiz [nessa resposta antiga no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13850882/540552) (ela está desatualizada/obsoleta, mas não deve ser muito difícil atualizá-la).